# NULL Datetime in a case statement

Tags: sql

When the Cursts is not cancelled I get a date like'

`(case when CURSTS ='cancelled' then CLOSEDDT else isnull((CANCELED_DTTM), null) end) as 'RFC Cancelled Date'`, the result is `01/01/1970  00:00:00` which I prefer to show as a blank i.e nothing

The output of SPROC is thrown into excel format.

Could you suggest modification to above script pls.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT case CURSTS  WHEN 'cancelled' then CLOSEDDT else CANCELED_DTTM end as 'RFC Cancelled Date'
```

Answer (score 0):

`isnull((CANCELED_DTTM), null)` won't do anything.  This says "If `CANCELED_DTTM` is null, then return null instead".

It sounds like your value isn't null anyways.  If you don't want the 1970 date, you can remove it...

```
CASE WHEN Canceled_DTTM = '01/01/1970  00:00:00' THEN NULL ELSE Canceled_DTTM END
```

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the response. I do ot have 'cancelled_DTTM' feild populated. so I have showing 'closeddate' @ 'cancelled_DTTM' only when CURSTS is 'cancelled' In other cases i.e where cursts is 'open' or 'closed' or anything else I want to show canceled_DTTM  blank. Its showing a default date format in from the system which is ''01/01/1970  00:00:00'